# MySQL Installer Stucks on "Starting Service"

Tags: mysql

I had problem with updating my last version of MySQL, so I removed everyting and just wanted to install a refresh version of the new MySQL 5.7, The problem is that it doesn't let me to install any version of that anymore. all of them stuck on configuration on starting service. I have already tried whatever I found on google but... NOTHING.

Here is the Log:

```
Beginning configuration step: Stopping Server [if necessary]
Ended configuration step: Stopping Server [if necessary]

Beginning configuration step: Writing configuration file
Ended configuration step: Writing configuration file

Beginning configuration step: Updating firewall
Adding firewall rule for MySQL57 on port 3306.
Successfully added firewall rule.
Ended configuration step: Updating firewall

Beginning configuration step: Adjusting Windows service [if necessary]
Attempting to grant Network Service require filesystem permissions.
Granted permissions.
Adding new service
New service added
Ended configuration step: Adjusting Windows service [if necessary]

Beginning configuration step: Initializing Database [if necessary]
Deleting Data folder shipped
Attempting to run MySQL Server with --Initialize-insecure
Running process: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe --          defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" --initialize-  insecure=on --console
Waiting for the server stops: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server     5.7\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server    5.7\my.ini" --initialize-insecure=on --console
2015-12-19T18:45:25.297629Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT   value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option   (see documentation for more details).
2015-12-19T18:45:25.297629Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE'    and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They    will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2015-12-19T18:45:26.485174Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created,   LSN=45790
2015-12-19T18:45:26.688242Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key  constraint system tables.
2015-12-19T18:45:26.797633Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so   we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started.    Generating a new UUID: ab7fc704-a680-11e5-8978-4c0bbe100c76.
2015-12-19T18:45:26.813276Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used.   Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2015-12-19T18:45:26.813276Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an   empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
Finished initialize database
Ended configuration step: Initializing Database [if necessary]

Beginning configuration step: Starting Server
Starting MySQL as a service
```

Comment: Try starting the service manually after installing. On Windows, just open task manager, select services, find the service and start it.

Comment: I did every thing, nothing helps!!!, Actually the status says Running, but it is still stuck on Starting Server...